# Pivot table top 10 filter is displaying more than 10 item

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have some sample data:

```
Fruit name | sales
Apple | 500
Banana | 100
Apple | 100
Pear | 
Apple | 100
```

As you can see, there is an empty value in Sales for the Pear.

I made a pivot table from this data, each row is Fruit, and value filter is Sum of Sales.

I applied a "top 10 sum of sales" filter to the pivot table.

I expected to only see the sum of sales for Banana and Apple, as they are the only ones with values.

However, the pivot table is displaying Pear as one of the rows as well.

In my real data, there are maybe 50 different fruits (actual number can vary), and sometimes, only 5 of the fruits have values in Sales column. So the top 10 filter ends up displaying all 50 fruits, with no value in the sum of sales. I strictly want only fruits with values in Sales to be displayed.

How do I make the fruits without value in Sales column, not appear in my pivot table? Would like to avoid solutions where I need to create a new column, then creating my pivot table from there, as this is part of a very large macro. Is there some sort of function or setting I am missing.

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/746870-pivot-table-top-10-list-excluding-blanks.html

Comment: Seems like the only solution is to use a helper column.

Comment: It makes sense. For Excel, a blank cell means 0, and 0 is a value.And if 0 is in TOP 10, it will show blank results.

Comment: James: Read that link above more carefully. There is another solution there, no helper column necessary.